# How to use schedule to run a job at 9:30am, repeat it at the top of every minute, and stop at 10:00am

Tags: python, scheduled-tasks

I have figured out how to use schedule to repeat a job at the top of every minute:

```
schedule.every().minute.at(":00").do(job)
```

But I can't figure out how to combine it with other schedule functions to start at a certain time (9:30am EST) and stop at a certain time (10:00am EST).

Comment: No because i need a combination of starting and stopping at a certain time AND repeating every minute in between the start and stop.

Comment: Is it an option to add `if now is not between 0930 and 1000: return;` at the start of `job()`?

Comment: why don't you let someone answer the question properly